# Can not access members outside

Tags: java

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public int page;
    public TableModel(Integer p) {                
        this.page=p;
        System.out.println("mm"+page);    
    }

    public void pudata() {
        System.out.println(page);
    }
    //System.out.println("model "+page);
    private String[] columnNames = {"groupName","membersCount","previliage"};

    public ArrayList<GroupData> data = (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size() ;
    }
```

Can not access variable `page` in `getgroup()` method it passes 0 to `getgroup()` method.

```
public ArrayList<GroupData> data = (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);
```

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the indentation - it's all over the place. And is all of this code within the same class? Bear in mind that all the initialization code will be run *at initialization* before the constructor is run - so yes, `page` will be 0 at that point.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to initialize a variable outside of a method. `page` is null by the time `data` is initialized...

Comment: public ArrayList<GroupData> data = 
        (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);
initialize this variable inside a constructor

Comment: move `data = 
            (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);
` to the constructor

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: No, it won't be null - it will be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear, but I *suspect* the problem is just that all the instance initializers are being run before the constructor body, so you're seeing the default value for `page`. You should have something like:

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    private static final String[] columnNames =
        {"groupName","membersCount","previliage"}; // TODO: Fix spelling!
    private final int page;
    private final List<GroupData> data;

    public TableModel(int page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.data = new DatabaseLayer().getGroup(page);
    }

    ...
}
```

It's generally a good idea to keep all your instance/static variable declarations in one place (I prefer to keep them at the top, but YMMV) and make them all private to make it easier to reason about how they're used. The main change, however, is moving the `new DatabaseLayer ().getGroup(page)` code into the constructor.

Comment: @SeniorJD: I have no idea what your comment means. Please give more details.

Comment: If the `page` field could be changed after the `TableModel` object initialized, the `data` would not be refreshed.

Comment: @SeniorJD: True, and I've made the variable final - but there's no indication that the OP wants that ability.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
    public int page;
    public ArrayList<GroupData> data;
    public TableModel(Integer p) {                
        this.page=p;
        this.data  = (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);
        System.out.println("mm"+page);    
    }

    public void pudata() {
        System.out.println(page);
    }
    //System.out.println("model "+page);
    private String[] columnNames = {"groupName","membersCount","previliage"};



    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return data.size() ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Refresh your `data` field every time when you assign a new value to the `page` field.

```
public TableModel(int p) {
    setPage(p);
}

public void setPage(int p) {
    this.page = p;
    this.data = new DatabaseLayer ().getGroup(page);
}
```

Comment: There's no indication that the OP even *wants* a `setPage` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is absolute correct because:

```
public int page;
```

default value for page is `0` because its `int`.

```
public ArrayList<GroupData> data = (new DatabaseLayer ()).getGroup(page);
```

Is a variable initialization so before initialization of `page` you are passing it into `.getGroup(page)` so default value will pass in that case.

So you have to call `getGroup(int)` method after `page` being initialized, one way can be following:

```
private final List<GroupData> data;

public TableModel(Integer p) {
    this.page = p;
    this.data = new DatabaseLayer().getGroup(page);
    System.out.println("mm"+page); 
}
```